# Weblogic t3 url configuration (using property file)

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x

Anybody know which property file or configuration file has the  T3 url for weblogic 12c server stored. I have to edit/change the T3 url via config/property file by logging into server. (not via management console). 
There is some constraint that I do not have to use management console. I want to change it via command prompt. I have googled this but couldn't find this info anywhere.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: are talking about the server's listen address ??

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Yes. Weblogic will have a T3 Protocol URL. Need to know the location in the server where I can modify?.  (Not from the management console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WLST in order to change the server's listen address.
WLST is under ${WL_HOME}/common/bin/wlst.sh
Commands :

```
connect("<USERNAME>","<PASSWORD","<HOST:PORT>")
edit()  
startEdit()  
cd("/Servers/<SERVER NAME>")  
set("ListenAddress","<NEW LISTEN ADDRESS>")  
save()  
activate()  
disconnect()
```